# join table on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables `user`, `student_data`, `teacher_data`. A user can be either student or a teacher. If it is the teacher I want to join `user` and `teacher_data`. And if it is a student then I want to join `user` with `student_data`.

How I can do this join with the condition.

Comment: Are the columns in the `teacher_data` table the same as those in the `student_data` table?  If they're different, what do you want to do about the differences?  If they're the same, why are they in two different tables?  Please demonstrate what you do and do not want to happen with example data, as recommended here: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd combine the two data tables in a sub-query, and then join the users to that.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  usr   u
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT user_id, datum, xxx, NULL AS yyy FROM student_data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT user_id, datum, NULL,        yyy FROM teacher_data
)
  d
    ON d.user_id = u.id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9b801ea739d42fe50c00ef4e17eaf143

***NOTES:***

- The columns selected from the two data tables must match
- Any unmatched columns must either be skipped or filled with NULL
- Please don't call a table `user`, it's a reserved keyword and Oracle won't allow it.

Comment: Thank you @matBailie, I was giving just an example. I will not use users in the oracle table.

Answer (score 2):

You can write it like this:

```
select   u.user_id,
         s.student_id,
         t.teacher_id
from usr u
left join student_data s  on u.user_id=s.student_id
left join teacher_data t  on u.user_id=t.teacher_id
where s.student_id is not null or t.teacher_id is not null
order by u.user_id
```

For every user_id check if he is a student or teacher, if he is student get his student column values else null, if he is a teacher get his teacher column values else null.

Comment: Can also blow up a bit if ever a student is also a teacher, depends on what the OP wants or is dealing with: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=371be3d32383a6d0dabb51d27d1a2768

Answer (score 0):

maybe try a union - something like this

```
select user_id, user_other_stuff
from user, student_data
where user.user_id = student_data.user_id
UNION
select user_id, user_other_stuff
from user, teacher_data
where user.user_id = teacher_data.user_id
```

Comment: ***Please*** don't perpetuate the use of implicit joins for SQL.  Three Decades of Ansi-92 JOIN syntax is plenty enough to have moved over by now.  *(It should also be `UNION ALL` to avoid the de-duplication overhead.)*